# Use a future subclass type in a base class method

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

Say I have a base class `BaseFoo` and a method to do something with a data structure composed entirely of BaseFoo:

```cs
public class BaseFoo { // FWIW, in my "real" example, this is an abstract base class
    public void Func(IEnumerable<BaseFoo> data) {
        // impl.
    }
}
```

Then I have some sub-classes, `Bar` and `Baz`:

```cs
public class Bar : BaseFoo {}
public class Baz : BaseFoo {}
```

But I realize that it's very important that my argument to `Func` contains objects of all the same type, and that the type matches the subclass! Disaster may strike if the inherited `Bar.Func` method is passed `new[] {new Bar(), new Baz()}`.

How can I enforce this in the declaration of `BaseFoo.Func`? (I can't use a generic `<T> where T : BaseFoo`, because the compiler would just use `BaseFoo` for `T`, and the bad example at the end of the last paragraph would compile.)

**Edit:**
Perhaps a better example: I want to store a list of `Bar`s in my `Bar` subclass, and similarly for `Baz`. But I want to write one declaration in `FooBase` for `List<this.GetType()>`, knowing full well that won't compile. I'm just looking for a way to use an arbitrary subclass's type *in the base class*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use *Generics*

**Example**

```
public class BaseFoo<T> where T : BaseFoo<T>
{
    public void Func(IEnumerable<T> data) { }
}

public class Bar : BaseFoo<Bar> {}
public class Baz : BaseFoo<Baz> {}
```

Which means

```
var bar = new Bar()
bar.Func(new List<bar>()) // can only ever take an enumerable of bar
```

<sub>***Disclaimer** : This disregards any other problem you might have conceptually or otherwise*</sub>

**Update**

I have added `where T : BaseFoo<T>` this is known as the [Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) in C++, inspired by the comments from [charlieface](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14868997/charlieface), also *Eric Lippert* has written about this in one of his blogs [Curiouser and curiouser](https://ericlippert.com/2011/02/02/curiouser-and-curiouser/).

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem, because someone could write `bar.Func(new List<BaseFoo>(new Baz()))`, and it would compile. Still +1 because it's straightforward.

Comment: See my clarifying edit. I'm wondering if there's some way to effectively use `this.GetType()` as a type parameter.

Comment: @WilliamBradley  this would not compile,  `bar.Func(new List<BaseFoo>(new Baz()))` the solution effectively limits all collections to that off the generic type of what is specified in the definition E.g `Bar : BaseFoo<Bar>` it can only even take a collection of `Bar`

Comment: @WilliamBradley see this example. https://dotnetfiddle.net/PAgaGa

Comment: Disadvantage of this solution is that `Bar` and `Baz` don't have a common base type anymore.

Comment: @SomeBody you are right. Which could be solved with an interface or more base type. I am a little busy atm, if you write an answer and explain that, or another approach, ping me and ill be more than happy to upvote

Comment: You should probably constrain `T` to `where T : BaseFoo<T>` this is called the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern

Comment: @Charlieface updated and attributed

Comment: You could still declare `Baz : BaseFoo<Bar>` and it would compile. There is no generic constraint that limits `T` to the declaring class.

Comment: @DStanley agreed, this is kind of a weird problem, and points to a separation of concerns issue

Comment: @DStanley Indeed, and that is because .NET does not have a constraint `where T : this` or similar, which would solve that problem